# Efficient dynamic clustering

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a set of datapoints from the unit interval (i.e. 1-dimensional dataset with numerical values). I receive some additional datapoints online, and moreover the value of some datapoints might change dynamically. I'm looking for an ideal clustering algorithm which can handle these issues efficiently.

I know [sequential k-means clustering](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall08/cos436/Duda/C/sk_means.htm) copes with the addition of new instances, and I suppose with minor modification it can work with dynamic instance values (i.e. first taking the modified instance from the respective cluster, then updating the mean of the cluster and finally giving the modified instance as an input to the algorithm just as the addition of an unseen instance).

My concern with using the k-means algorithm is the requirement of supplying the number of clusters as an input. I know that they beat other clustering algorithms (GAs, MSTs, Hierarchical Methods etc.) in time&space complexity. Honestly I'm not sure, but maybe I can get away with using one of the aforementioned algorithms. Even that my datasets are relatively large, the existence of a single dimension makes me wonder.

More specifically a typical test case of mine would contain about 10K-200K 1-dimensional datapoints. I would like to complete the clustering preferably under a second. The dynamic changes in the value points are assumed to be smooth, i.e. relatively small. Thus being able to use existing solutions (i.e. being able to continue clustering on the existing one when a value is changed or new one is added) is highly preferred.

So all in all:

> Can you think of an algorithm which will provide a sweet spot between computational efficiency and the accuracy of clusters wrt. the problem defined above?
>
> Are there some nice heuristics for the k-means algorithm to automatically compute the value of K beforehand?

Comment: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ would be more relevant a place to ask this good question :)

Answer (score 1):

Because your dataset is 1-dimensional, you have available a very simple and efficient means of dynamically updating clusters according to the [single-linkage clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering) rule.  This rule states that 2 clusters are joined into 1 whenever there is a point from the first cluster and a point from the second cluster that are below some prespecified threshold distance.

- Build a [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) containing your initial set of points.
- Make an initial O(n) inorder pass through this BST, which visits the nodes in sorted order, to find the initial set of clusters: each time the distance between the current point and the last is less than the threshold, add it to the previous cluster, otherwise start a new cluster.
- When dynamically adding a point X, simply search for its two neighbours L and R (one on either side) in the BST and insert it as usual.  If X - L < threshold, then X joins L's cluster; if R - X < threshold, then X joins R's cluster; if both are true, then L's cluster and R's cluster must be combined; and if none are true then X forms its own, new cluster.
- When dynamically removing a point X, find its neighbours L and R as before, and if they currently belong to the same cluster C, check whether R - L > threshold.  If it does, scan left (or right) from X, putting every point into a new cluster until you find a point that is not in C.
- A move is equivalent to a deletion followed by an insertion.

You can record what cluster each point belongs to in a field within each BST node.  Alternatively, if insertions predominate, then it will probably be faster to use a [union/find data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Answer (score 0):

Other approach than BST(or decision trees) is hierarchical clustering like [BIRCH algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIRCH_%28data_clustering%29) which is well suited for large datasets and adding new data points into existing clusters, also it's performance is one of the best